# Chapter review “ Find the indicated derivative”

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Find $y'$ if 
$$y = 6x^2 - 10 + \frac{12}{x^2}$$
I feel like this is an easy question but I am drawing a blank on how to do it. If someone could help explain in steps how to do this problem so I can do the next similar one would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a straight differentiation. Could you do it for $y=6x^2$?

Comment: Sum rule and power rule are some of the most basic concepts in differentiation. $$(f(x)+g(x))'=f'(x)+g'(x)$$ $$(ax^b)'=abx^{b-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the [power rule for derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule):
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^r)=rx^{r-1},$$

and the [sum/subtraction rules for derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules):

$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)+g(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))+\frac{d}{dx}(g(x)),$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)-g(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))-\frac{d}{dx}(g(x)).$$

Where

$$r=2: \quad \frac{d}{dx}(6x^2)=6\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=6( 2x)=12x,$$
$$r=-2: \quad \frac{d}{dx}(12x^{-2})=12\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(x^{-2})=12(-2x^{-3})=-24x^{-3},$$

and the derivative of any constant function is zero. So, $\frac{d}{dx}(10)=0$.
Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

We can apply the simple properties of differentiation as such: 
$$y = 6x^2 - 10 + \frac{12}{x^2}$$
$$ y'= 6(2x)-0+12 \cdot \frac{-2}{x^3}$$
I leave it to you to figure out the "simple properties"...

Comment: So the answer would be 12x + 12 • (-2/x^3)

Comment: @JohnnyDanger18: Yes, $12x+12\left(\frac{-2}{x^3}\right)=12x-\frac{24}{x^3}$.

Comment: Thank you. I did the next problem would you be able to tell me if I did it correct or not? Same type of problem. Find f’(t) if f(t) = t^3 • e^(4t)  for this problem I got 24t